# Unable to login to jenkins with valid credentials

Tags: authentication, jenkins, passwords, credentials

I'm having trouble in signing in to our Jenkins Server with any valid credentials. First I thought there is some problem with 1 of the credentials, so I turned off the security through config.xml and reset the password through GUI and also proof-checked that passwordhash has changed in config.xml, but still couldn't login through even with the newly changed credentials. How can I fix this problem, it's a security problem if I leave our jenkins server without authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered. I will post a solution here, in case somebody face this problem too. 1st of all I turned off security in config.xml and could use jenkins as Anonymous User. Deleted the old not working user and created a new account with same name as old User. Turned on security and could use the new user in same way like old user.